# Writing Output of ODBC Query to Text file

Tags: c#, datatable, odbc, row

I am having trouble with the below code in writing the data to output text file, it's writing the column names fine but not the containing row (1);

I am getting the following error:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt
> to call Read when reader is closed.    at
> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.Read()    at
> Testing_Studio.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Testing_Studio\Program.cs:line 31

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace Testing_Studio
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String sqlQuery = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Testing_Studio\Script_2.txt");
            //display query: Console.WriteLine(sqlQuery);

            {
                //create connection
                OdbcCommand comm = new OdbcCommand();
                comm.Connection = new odbcConnection("Dsn=Test;uid=Test;pwd=Test");

                 comm.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                 comm.Connection.Open();

                 OdbcDataReader sqlReader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                 var dataTable = new DataTable(); 
                 dataTable.Load(sqlReader);
                 // Open the file for write operations.  If exists, it will overwrite due to the "false" parameter
                 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Testing_Studio\output.txt"))
                 {
                      while (sqlReader.Read())
                      {
                          //// get column names
                          var columnNames = dataTable.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName);

                          //// write column names row
                         writer.WriteLine(String.Join("\t", columnNames));

                        //// get column count
                        int columnCount = dataTable.Columns.Count;
                        Console.WriteLine(columnCount);
                        //// array to hold data values
                        string[] values = new string[columnCount];

                        //// write columns in each row
                        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                        {   
                             for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                             {
                                  object value = row[i];
                                  //// check row value for null
                                  values[i] = (value != null) ? value.ToString() : "NULL";
                                  Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
                             }
                             //// write data line
                             writer.WriteLine(String.Join("\t", values));
                        }  
                    }
                }
                sqlReader.Close();
                comm.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Many Thanks for the support!

Comment: Calling _DataTable.Load(IDataReader)_ will fill the table and then closes the reader. So you cannot use it afterward. And there is no reason to use it again. Your data is already in the datatable. Remove the while loop over the datareader because it is useless

Comment: Lovely, removing the while loop worked a charm, thanks!

Comment: You can self-answer to your question. So I suggest you to explain how you fix this with Steve's comment, and share your current working code (in your self-answer obviously)